# Querying 2 taxonomies and meta query Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help about Wordpress Query. I have 2 taxonomies so I used `tax_query` and for the meta post I used `meta_query`. My problem is I want to get all the data by searching Specialty,Insurance or zip code.

Sample Code

```
$result_specialties = $_REQUEST['arr_spec'];
$result_insurance = $_REQUEST['arr_insur']; 
$zip_code = $_REQUEST['zip_code'];

//get term_id
$cat_spec = get_term_by( 'name' , $result_specialties, 'specialty' );
$get_spec_id =  $cat_spec->term_id;


$cat_insu = get_term_by( 'name' , $result_insurance, 'insurance' );
$get_insu_id =  $cat_insu->term_id;

//query 2 taxonomies
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sample_post',
    'relation' => 'OR', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'zip_code',
            'value'   => $zip_code,
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),  
    'tax_query' => array (
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'specialty',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => array( $get_spec_id ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'insurance',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => array( $get_insu_id ),
        ),  
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This is what I've tried. `meta_query` and `tax_query` is doing good if I comment each one of them. for example I comment the `meta_query` and the `tax_query` will work fine. but if I used them both it will not work. Please help me if you have idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: maybe helpful  to you...

```
    $result_specialties = $_REQUEST['arr_spec'];
    $result_insurance = $_REQUEST['arr_insur']; 
    $zip_code = $_REQUEST['zip_code'];

    //get term_id
    $cat_spec = get_term_by( 'name' , $result_specialties, 'specialty' );
    $get_spec_id =  $cat_spec->term_id;


    $cat_insu = get_term_by( 'name' , $result_insurance, 'insurance' );
    $get_insu_id =  $cat_insu->term_id;

    //query 2 taxonomies
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'sample_post', 
        'meta_key' => 'zip_code', 
        'meta_value'   => $zip_code, 
        'tax_query' => array (
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'specialty',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => array( $get_spec_id ),
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'insurance',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => array( $get_insu_id ),
            ),  
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: hi vrajesh thanks for your reply. taxonomy is working but if I only search by zip code still not working. I've tried to print $zip_code and it is also passing the parameter. I think the problem is in the query.

Comment: i remove 'relation' in wp_query $args ..but not in sub tax_query array...now please check